# Lost files when opening Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio

I used git push code to azure dev after pushing the code the first time, when I reopened the code with the Visual Studio 2022 .sln file, it was locked as shown and no files appeared. When opening Visual Studio with "Open Folder", some folders are lost so the code cannot be run. I tried to clone the code and pull it again, but the file still does not appear when opened in Visual Studio 2022

[image: Problem With Visual Studio]

Comment: Do you get an error on compile or when you try to run the code? Also, git will ignore empty folders by default. If those are essential, either make sure they exist in code, in a pre-build action or force git to add them.

Comment: My code follows the ABP Boilerplate structure, but for some reason, when I push the code to Azure Dev and reopen Visual Studio, I don't see any files.

Comment: Can you give a detailed list of the exact steps you take? This must be a layer 8. Thousands of people do this every day.

Comment: Step 1: I code according to the Boilerplate structure
Step 2: I push the code to azure dev, in visual studio, locks appear in the files as shown and when I reopen the project with .sln, the entire folder structure is lost.

Comment: How do you push? Where do you click, what do type? It sounds like that is the step that messed up. Do you get error messages? If you need to, add Screenshots of the Buttons you push to the question.

Comment: Visual Studio has two modes in the Solution pane. You're currently looking at the "project" version. If you added files to the directory without actually including them in one of the projects, you might see them by switching to the Explorer view (it's the left-most icon at the top of the pane). Basically, that will show you the same thing you'd see in Windows Explorer.

Comment: I fixed it by creating a new folder then cloned it to another copy and everything was ok. Perhaps the problem is still in the .git file of the old folder